# From iPhone 5 project to iPhone 6 and Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I had a project for iPhone 4 and 5 and now I am considering to make it supported for iphone 6 and 6+.

I wrote everything in code, i.e. no `xib` or `storyboard`, so some UI element was specified absolute size. For example, there is a `UIImageView` in a `tableView`'s cell:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
```

Currently, I have not yet added launch image for iphone 6 and plus, so these views are scaled version in iphone 6 and plus.

My question is if I added launch images, do I need to specify different frames for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus? This is gonna be a huge task, as I need to add tons of codes.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, it is the best time switch to XIB or Storyboard instead of setting the frame through code. If you use Auto Resize/Layout mechanism then you may don't need to much worry about these issues when Apple introduce a new device. And it is definitly going to reduce your efforts to support a newer resolution.

Comment: Doing all stuff from code may make sense when you have more that couple of developers in your team and all of them are editing UI part of project. So you will have a lot of troubles with storyboards during work with VCS. And moving to xib or storyboard will also require a lot of work

Comment: @Azat then what you suggest?.

Comment: My suggestion is to modify code to use relative sizes

Answer (score 1):

Relative size = use no absolute numbers, or using view's autoresizingMask property to keep relative arrangement。

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus support you need to add `LaunchScreen.xib` file to you project. And yes, you are right, all you static sizes that were relying on standard iPhone width will be broken at that moment. So it would be better to use relative sizes than absolute

Comment: what do you mean by relative sizes? How do I do that?

Comment: @user2053760 i.e. you have `tableView`'s cell with `UIImage`, `UILabel` and `UISwitch`. My suggestion is define `width` for `UIImage` and `UISwitch` and let `UILabel` fill all remain space by defining it's `width` as `superview`'s `width` minus `image` and `switch` width minus margins